# Show ng-message content only when validation fails in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found some custom code online for simple login form:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && vm.login()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.username.$invalid }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
            <div ng-messages="form.$submitted && form.username.$error" class="help-block">
                <div ng-message="required">Username is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.password.$invalid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
            <div ng-messages="form.$submitted && form.password.$error" class="help-block">
                <div ng-message="required">Password is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Currently, ng-messages with content: 'Username is required' and 'Password is required' are always visible. 
Is there any chance I can change this code in a way I see that messages only when authentication fails?

Or in other words can I hide them in HTML, because I guess I have to show them through angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `ng-if` on your div, checking for the errors:

```
ng-if="form.password.$error"
ng-if="form.username.$error"
```

This will ensure that the div only shows if an error in your form exists, specific to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormController.$dirty` or `FormController.$pristine`

By Angular Docs:

> $pristine: True if user has not interacted with the form yet.
>
> $dirty: True if user has already interacted with the form.

```
<div ng-if="form.$dirty && vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
```